# How to get value of 2 different radio box and set it to specific place using loop/each?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('.allrb').change(function() {
    valueE();
  });

});  


function valueE()
{
  for(j=0; j<=2 ; j++)
  {
    var nofr1=[];  
    row=document.getElementsByName("Fr"+j);
      for (i=0; i<row.length; i++)
      {
        if(row[i].checked)
          nofr1[i]= parseInt(row.value);
      }
    $("#numFr"+(j+1)).val(nofr1[j]); 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">
<tr id="alertr1" name="v">
  <td width="200px" id="text">content 1</td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb" value="0"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb" value="1"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb" value="2"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb" value="3"></label></td>
  <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb" value="4"></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
  <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
  <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr1" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
  <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr1" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
</tr>

<tr id="alertr2" name="v">
  <td width="200px" id="text">content 2</td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb" value="0"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb" value="1"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb" value="2"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb" value="3"></label></td>
  <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb" value="4"></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
  <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
  <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr2" id="numFr2" disabled></td>
  <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr2" id="numIr2" disabled></td>
</tr>

<tr id="alertr3" name="v">
  <td width="200px" id="text">content 3</td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb" value="0"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb" value="1"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb" value="2"></label></td>
  <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb" value="3"></label></td>
  <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb" value="4"></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
  <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
  <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
  <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr3" id="numFr3" disabled></td>
  <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr3" id="numIr3" disabled></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

In a row, I have 2 different radio box, how to I get the value of all of the radio box and set the value in the specific `input[type=number]` there? Since I had 16 row and each row had 2 different value box, I would like to use loop to loop all the value into specific place, else there will be many redundant code. I had try to do it, but my jquery won't work. Thanks.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. You have several rows. In each row you have two groups of radio inputs. For each row, you want to take the value from the first group and assign it to an array and then move on to the next group and take that groups value and assign it to the next spot in the array. And you want to repeat this for each row?

Comment: @Darkisa Yes, example: When I click the 2nb radio button for the first group radio box, then my input[type=number] of the first group will display 1( value=1), and when I click 3rd button for the second group, the input[type=number] of second group will display 2(value=2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element that is changed can be referenced on the event.  If you give the input you want to update a common class, you can find the one that is related to your radios by finding the radios parent tr, and finding that class within.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.allrb').change(valueE);
});


function valueE(e) {
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  var $radio = $(e.target);
  
  if ($radio.is('.Fr')) {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numFr').val(newValue);
  } else {
    $radio.closest('tr').find('.numIr').val(newValue);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="tab">
  <tr id="alertr1" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 1</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr1" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir1" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr1" class="numFr" id="numFr1" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr1" class="numIr" id="numIr1" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr2" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 2</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr2" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir2" class="allrb Ir" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr2" class="numFr" id="numFr2" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr2" class="numIr" id="numIr2" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="alertr3" name="v">
    <td width="200px" id="text">content 3</td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="0"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="1"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="2"></label></td>
    <td width="40px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="3"></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><label><input type="radio" name="Fr3" class="allrb Fr" value="4"></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="0" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir Ir3" class="allrb" value="1" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="2" ></label></td>
    <td width="50px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="3" ></label></td>
    <td width="120px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><label><input type="radio" name="Ir3 Ir" class="allrb" value="4" ></label></td>
    <td width="30px"><input type="number" name="numFr2" class="numFr" id="numFr2" disabled></td>
    <td width="30px" bgcolor="Gainsboro"><input type="number" name="numIr3" class="numIr" id="numIr3" disabled></td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but when I click for the second group of radio box, the value will also change in the first input[type=number] =O

Comment: What I means is when I select the first group of radio box(without grey color)  the value display in first input number box(without grey color),which is correct. But when I select for second group of radio box(with grey color), then the value will change in first input number box(without grey color), which is wrong. Should change in the second input number (with grey color) there.

Comment: @Beginner updated so that the second radios target the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you without changing the HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.allrb').change(valueE);
});

function valueE(e) {
    var index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
  var newValue = e.target.value;
  if ($(this).closest("td").attr("bgcolor") == "Gainsboro"){
     $("#numIr" + (index + 1)).val(newValue);  
  }else $("#numFr" + (index + 1)).val(newValue);  
}
```

However, this won't work for your first radio group of the last row since your input has an `id="numFr2"`, which I believe you meant to label as `id="numFr3"` Once you correct the name it will work for that one as well.

Comment: Thanks, I try it already, but the input number had skip for 2 row. Mean that when I select radio button for row 1, the result will display at row 3

Comment: That shouldn't be the case unless you changed your HTML. Here is the working fiddle based on your original HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/wmw4fqv1/

Comment: Opp, sorry, you are right, your code is working fine,I had check my code and can work already. Thank you!